# I have an issue with bbpress and tinymce editor - TypeError: n.quirks is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have an issue with bbpress and tinymce.When I click on add video/ add photo. The box comes up, i can paste my code or upload the picture. but when I try to press ok nothing happens. can you solve this?

But when i check via console this problem showing [image]
my wordpress version 4.7.2
bbpress Version 2.5.12
TinyMCE Advanced Version 4.4.3

**Note this problem only showing in front-end editor(i mean bbpress forum editor)**